# why treeview control does not load the data properly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i receive this data and after conversion to `json` format as follows:

```
[{"id":"2","text":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION","parent":"1"},{"id":"9","text":"MARITAL STATUS","parent":"1"},{"id":"13","text":"Recreational drug use","parent":"1"},{"id":"14","text":"OCCUPATION","parent":"1"},{"id":"16","text":" 1 child","parent":"1"},{"id":"17","text":" 2/3/4/5/6 children","parent":"1"},{"id":"18","text":"Activities","parent":"1"},{"id":"27","text":"Tobacco Use","parent":"1"},{"id":"37","text":"SocHx  Template","parent":"1"}]
```

currently the above `json` data is in the view

```
@{      
     var j2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allparents);    
}
```

and the `j2` has the above `json`. `json` data works as expected.When i tried to bind the coming data to `jstree` control it would not add the nodes properly

here is my jquery code to bind data

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Div_jstree').jstree(
                       {
                           "json_data": { "data": '@j2' }, 
                           "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
                       }
                   );  
        });


    </script>
}


//the below is the generated HTML copied from chrome elements option
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <div id="Div_jstree" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default jstree-leaf" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="j1_loading" aria-busy="false"><ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group"></ul></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="Div_txta"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="utctime"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

as you can see only some parts of the `jstree` control were loaded, but where is my data?

Comment: What is the HTML source of this page after rendering?  Is it possible that the razor parser is not smart enough to intercept the `'@j2'` where you have it and is just leaving it as-is?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your issue is that you need to use `Html.Raw()` on your json variable.  In performing a test locally, without `Raw` the quotation marks were being formatted improperly:

```
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
      var myObj =
      {
         "json_data": { "data": '@Html.Raw(j2)' },
         "json_data2": { "data": '@j2' },
         "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
      };

      alert(myObj);

   });


</script>
```

Results in the following when you view the HTML source after rendering:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var myObj =
      {
         "json_data": { "data": '[{"id":"2","text":"ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION","parent":"1"},{"id":"9","text":"MARITAL STATUS","parent":"1"},{"id":"13","text":"Recreational drug use","parent":"1"},{"id":"14","text":"OCCUPATION","parent":"1"},{"id":"16","text":" 1 child","parent":"1"},{"id":"17","text":" 2/3/4/5/6 children","parent":"1"},{"id":"18","text":"Activities","parent":"1"},{"id":"27","text":"Tobacco Use","parent":"1"},{"id":"37","text":"SocHx  Template","parent":"1"}]' },
         "json_data2": { "data": '[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;13&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Recreational drug use&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;16&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot; 1 child&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot; 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Activities&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template&quot;,&quot;parent&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]' },
         "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
      };

;
```